# How to generate a new Guid in stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I currently have a stored procedure in which I want to insert new rows into a table.

```sql
insert into cars
(id, Make, Model)
values('A new Guid', "Ford", "Mustang")
```

So the primary key 'id' is a Guid. I know how to create a new Guid in C# code but within the stored procedure I'm unsure how to generate the new Guids for the primary key values.

Answer (score 183, accepted):

With SQL Server you can use the function [NEWID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx). You're using C# so I assume that you're using SQL Server. I'm sure other database system have similar functions.

```
select NEWID()
```

If you're using Oracle then you can use the [`SYS_GUID()`](http://psoug.org/definition/SYS_GUID.htm) function. Check out the answer to this question: [Generate a GUID in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3037511/21353)

Answer (score 29):

Try this:

```
SELECT NewId()
```

Answer (score 12):

You didn't ask about this in your question, but I think it's worth pointing out that using a GUID for a primary key is not always a good idea. While it's simple, it can affect performance when a GUID is used in an index. Have you considered using an [Identity column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) that is an integer value instead?

Here are a couple of articles that might be helpful to read.

- [Performance Effects of Using GUIDs
  as Primary Keys](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/performance/performance-effects-of-using-guids-as-primary-keys.aspx) (SQL Server
  Magazine)
- [Primary Keys: IDs versus
  GUIDs](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/primary-keys-ids-versus-guids.html) (Jeff Atwood)
- [The Cost of GUIDs as Primary Keys](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=25862) (Jimmy Nelson's article referenced by the two other articles)

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. However I'm working on a database which someone else developed. All the previous tables used a Guid as a primary key so I'm just trying to be consistent. Though for new tables maybe I should evaluate on a case by case basis. Thanks for the info though.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL it is UUID().
so the query would be:

```
insert into cars
(id, Make, Model)
values(UUID(), "Ford", "Mustang")
```

if you want to reuse the uuid you can do it like this:

```
set @id=UUID();
insert into cars
(id, Make, Model)
values(@id, "Ford", "Mustang");
select @id;
```

Comment: both tested in mysql

Answer (score 1):

In the format of the question (spot the pedant!)

```
insert into cars
  (id, Make, Model)
  values(NEWID(), "Ford", "Mustang")
```