# generate guid for every row in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I Have a stored procedure that has a table with one column and I need to generate a NEWID() for each row in that column.  Would I only be able to accomplish this with a loop?

```
+---+    +--------------------------------------+---+
| a |    | FD16A8B5-DBE6-46AB-A59A-6B6674E9A78D | a |
| b | => | 9E4A6EE6-1C95-4C7F-A666-F88B32D24B59 | b |
| c |    | 468C0B23-5A7E-404E-A9CB-F624BDA476DA | c |
+---+    +--------------------------------------+---+
```

Comment: A loop is not necessary and generally speaking you should try to avoid loops in SQL Server, using set-based operations instead (as demonstrated in the accepted answer from @bluefeet).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate a new Guid in stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938113/how-to-generate-a-new-guid-in-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to select from your table and include the `newid()` to generate the value for each row:

```
select newid(), col
from yourtable;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d6aff/1)

Comment: What if I needed to have access to the value created by newid() somewhere within the same query?

Comment: @Joe My suggestion would be to post a new question with your new requirements.

Answer (score 8):

You can create a column with the new guid

```
alter table yourtable add id varchar(40) not null default NEWID()
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b3c31/1

Answer (score 0):

newid() will definately work.  But will also create "fragmented" values.

This may be beneficial or detrimental (think guid as a Primary Key) to your needs.

Here is a procedure I wrote a while back to "kinda help" with fragmentation.

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[uspNewSequentialUUIDCreateSingle]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspNewSequentialUUIDCreateSingle]
GO

/*

--START TEST

declare @returnCode int
declare @ReturnUUID uniqueidentifier

EXEC @returnCode = dbo.uspNewSequentialUUIDCreateSingle @ReturnUUID output
print @ReturnUUID
print '/@returnCode/'
print @returnCode


--loop test,,,loop exists for TESTING only fyi

declare @counter int
select @counter = 1000

while @counter > 0
    begin
        EXEC @returnCode = dbo.uspNewSequentialUUIDCreateSingle @ReturnUUID output
        print @ReturnUUID
        select @counter = @counter - 1
    end


--END TEST CODE


*/

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspNewSequentialUUIDCreateSingle] (
@ReturnUUID uniqueidentifier output  --return
)

AS


--//You can use NEWSEQUENTIALID() to generate GUIDs to reduce page contention at the leaf level of indexes.

SET NOCOUNT ON 

--      declare @ReturnUUID uniqueidentifier

declare @t table ( id int , uuid uniqueidentifier default newsequentialid() )
insert into @t ( id ) values (0)
select @ReturnUUID = uuid from @t



SET NOCOUNT OFF
GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.uspNewSequentialUUIDCreateSingle TO public

GO
```