# SQL Server: Return unique generated value for each row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The requirement is to return unique value for each processed row from stored procedure, which will be used like dummy primary key. One solution seems to be using ROW_NUMBER() function. Another one is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045138/how-do-i-generate-random-number-for-each-row-in-a-tsql-select). Perhaps, there can be solutions involving Guid. Can someone recommend me a solution which is performant and reliable?

Comment: please look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839420/generate-guid-for-every-row-in-a-column

Comment: The answer depends on the context in which you plan to use the stored procedure.

Comment: Whats happening in the SP and how are you returning values?  For example if you have a select statement at the end of the SP you can take one approach, if you are returning a table variable via an output parameter you could use another approach.

Answer (score 0):

- A random number would not be an option (as you specify *unique*).
- `ROW_NUMBER` is a bigint taking up 8 bytes of storage per row.
- `uniqueidentifier` is a 16 byte structure and more costly to obtain than a `ROW_NUMBER` which is simply incremented (SQL's unique identifiers are GUIDs, with `NEWID()` being slower than `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` because `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` will increment from a seed GUID).
- In scenarios where you `INSERT` into a table variable or a temporary table, you can use `IDENTITY`. Storage size is that of the column data type, which can be any integer type (no bit, no decimal). It will increment from a configurable offset (default 1), in configurable step (default 1).

**This seems to make `ROW_NUMBER` your best fit, it is both fast and reliable.**

I would recommend to base your design choice on more than just performance though. On any reasonably configured SQL server installation you will barely notice a difference in speed, and unless you have very constrained resources, storage should not be the bottleneck either. Some rather old [benchmarks here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32597/Performance-Comparison-Identity-x-NewId-x-NewSeque).

Be aware that neither will help you to maintain or guarantee a particular order of the returned rows - you still need to `ORDER BY` your outermost `SELECT` if you need predicable results.