# Oracle regexp_replace string cleanse in SQL query returning full dataset, not just mismatching rows

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, string-comparison, regexp-replace

I'm using Oracle REGEXP_REPLACE to remove all non standard ascii (special) characters from a CLOB freetext field a client uses to store data, some users copy and paste from Excel which causes issues when reading the text from the CLOB. I've managed to get rid of all special characters and maintain the layout for paragraphs etc.

The issue I'm having is when I compare the cleansed field to the original, after converting to char string of course, is it is returning rows that have no difference between them, I've pulled out both values and there is no difference in most cases. 
It's returning the whole dataset instead of just those that have been cleansed.I've run out of ideas

FYI a big part of maintaining the layout means I need to keep the carriage return CHR(13)

Below is the query

```
select *
from (
select incident, entity,
trim(to_char(textarea)) textarea,
trim(to_char(regexp_replace(textarea,'[^' || CHR(13) || CHR(32) || '-' || CHR(126) || ']',''))) regexp_text
from response
) tab
where tab.regexp_text <> tab.textarea
```

I've tried a number of different combinations with trimming whitespace and substring smaller strings etc. with no luck

Comment: Can you please post some example data, showing the expected and the actual result?

Comment: @Aleksej The expected result would be strings that don't match i.e `éklzéiuhkn` and `klziuhkn` except it's also returning strings that match as well as ones that don't

Comment: You could use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22533037/how-to-call-oracle-md5-hash-function to calculate the MD5 checksum for both result columns, to see if they are *really* identical.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is:  `'[^' || CHR(13) || CHR(32) || '-' || CHR(126) || ']'`.

The caret (`^`) is replacing everything that is *not* a special character with an empty string.  With Oracle's default settings, I would expect this to return the empty string, which is treated as a `NULL` -- but that would mean nothing is returned.

In any case, try removing the caret:

```
trim(to_char(regexp_replace(textarea, '[CHR(13) || CHR(32) || '-' || CHR(126) || ']',' '))) as regexp_text
```

Comment: This would not explain the described behaviour, though.

Comment: @GordonLinoff When i remove the caret it does the opposite and removes all characters except special

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH data ( value ) AS (
  SELECT 'éklzéiuhkn' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE( value, '[^\r -~]', '' )
FROM   data;
```

**Outputs**:

```
REGEXP_R
--------
klziuhkn
```

So your query should be something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT incident,
         entity,
         TRIM( textarea ) AS textarea,
         TRIM( REGEXP_REPLACE( textarea, '[^\r -~]', '' ) ) AS regexp_text
  FROM   response
)
WHERE textarea <> regexp_text;
```

Comment: I need to maintain the carriage return

Comment: @KevinT swapped from `\n` to `\r`.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out, the issue was in formatting the comparisson strings in the `where` clause to include all Ascii characters  and match against the regexp I planned to use, it was the only way to eliminate bogus and invisible encoded characters.

```
select incident, entity,
regexp_replace(textarea,'[^' || CHR(13) || ' -}‘-~À-ü]',''))) regexp_text
regexp_replace(textarea,'[^' || CHR(13) || CHR(32) || '-' || CHR(125) || CHR(145) || '-' || CHR(152) || CHR(192) || '-' || CHR(252) || ']','') regexp_text2
from response
where to_char(regexp_replace(textarea,'[^' || CHR(163) || CHR(1) || '-' || CHR(125) || CHR(145) || '-' || CHR(152) || CHR(192) || '-' || CHR(252) || ']','')) <> to_char(regexp_replace(textarea,'[^' || CHR(1) || '-' || CHR(255) || ']',''))
```

I included both lines to show the simple regexp of `'[^' || CHR(13) || ' -}‘-~À-ü]'` as well as the `CHR(x)` version.
I also needed to include latin characters in the end.

For some reason using only CHR() when specifing ascii characters works 100% of the time, I guess it might have something to do with the environments NLS_LANG setting.

This should work for all those looking to exclude weird encoded characters from their strings