# Hashbytes equivalent in Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a function in Oracle -sql (pl/sql) . 
what is the equivalent for HASHBYTES in oracle pl/ql.

Comment: what is the version of Oracle database, you are using ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call Oracle MD5 hash function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22533037/how-to-call-oracle-md5-hash-function)