# The MD5 oracle function gives different output compared to the online md5 generator

Tags: oracle, plsql, md5, md5sum

Here's the code I am trying :

```
declare
     l_body varchar2(4000):='{
    "redirect":"https:www.oracle.com",
    "username":"rashmi.gangatkar",
    "verified":1
    }';
     l_md5 varchar2(4000);
     begin
     dbms_output.put_line(l_body);
     select dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.md5(input => utl_raw.cast_to_raw(l_body))  into l_md5 from dual;
     dbms_output.put_line(l_md5);
    
     end;
```

And this returns : EC18073656B941388BFD41B68CCAB72E

When the same input is passed in any online MD5 generators, it returns
bcf8c80e42d53c1758f8c3ca83cc5774

Is there something that, I am missing. If the input is a single line statement, the output matches.
Only issue when it is multiple lines.

Thank you.

Comment: DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT is deprecated so you should no longer be using that.  Also, this question is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22533037/how-to-call-oracle-md5-hash-function

Comment: Different *new line* character could cause the difference (CR LF)

Comment: so I tried using ||chr(13)||chr(10)|| and it worked.