# How to generate guids for oracle multi row inserts

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, guid

I have to insert several rows into an Oracle sql table. Like

```
insert into table (col1, col2, col_unique_guid) select col1, "bla", sys_guid() from source_table;
```

Unfortunately sys_guid() is the same for all rows - is there a way maybe over sequences to insert indiviual guids for each row?

Comment: Did you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037462/how-to-generate-a-guid-in-oracle

The guids are very similar but they are different. Just to be sure, check it again!

Comment: Do you have a unique constraint or primary key on `col_unique_guid`?

Comment: Can you show generated result set with the same result  as you say ?

Comment: @Ringelmann I'm seeing the same behvaiour on Oracle 12.2.0.1 with a less straightforward (but essentially the same) statement INSERT INTO TABLE SELECT * FROM (...) where sys_guid() is called in the (...) portion. I've had to create an INSERT trigger to insert the primary key as a work around.

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce your issue, but in some situations oracle may 'optimize' the function call in a query in a way that the function is called only once during query execution.

You can force Oracle to call the function for each row by writing a wrapper function and passing the rownum to it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function get_my_guid(i number) return raw
is
begin
  return sys_guid();
end;
/
```

e.g.:

```
insert into test_guid (col1, col2, col_unique_guid) select col1, col2, get_my_guid(rownum) from test_guid_src;
```